# How to install and configure LAMP

Tags: webserver, lamp

First of all I am new to Linux. I got a CentOS 6.0 64 Bit VPS and want to use it as a web server. I have searched on Google and SO and found many tutorials on LAMP setup, however all of them are different when it comes to configuration part. (for example for folder privileges one use chmod 750 and another one uses chmod 2750 and another uses something different but I cant get the difference)

I want to setup a reliable web server which is secure and light as possible.

Can you tell me where to start or suggest some good tutorials on LAMP configuration?

Comment: It might be better to post this in SuperUser.com. Not necessary though. :)

Comment: in addition to Eduan, I have to tell you just google LAMP CentOS, you'll find a lot of pages explaining it step by step

Comment: I have tried serverfault but for a reason they closed my question :/

Comment: Yes I googled it and all of the results are different than the other, I want to learn instead of copy pasting commands

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-centos-6) is so good for starting with LAMP on CentOS.